# how to check exist one element in another element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have one element that  I want check inside it... if another (div element) exist in it show me one alert else if don't exist show me another alert.

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="totti"></div>
   <div id="xavi"></div>
   <div id="ronaldo"></div>
   <div id="figo"></div>
</div>
```

I want check exist this div inside parent elemet???

```
<div id="messi"></div>
```

Comment: `$("#parent:has(#messi)")` it returns boolean value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) in combination with [.find](http://api.jquery.com/find):

```
if($("#parent").find("#messi").length) {
  alert("It exists!");
}
else {
  alert("It doesn't exist");
}
```

Or simply use a selector:

```
if($("#parent #messi").length) {
  // alert
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#parent").find("#mess1") != undefined){
    console.log("exists");
} else console.log("doesn't exist");
```

This would give you the DOM object with the id "mess1".

More info [here](http://api.jquery.com/find/).